# Accessing uTorrent webUI from outside network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firewall, port-forwarding, bittorrent

I am trying to configure the uTorrent webUI for access outside my home wifi network.

I am able to access it on the local machine using localhost:7070/gui, but cannot access it externally using my dynamic dns (e.g. me.dynu.com:7070/gui).

I am able to access other services absolutely fine through this method on other ports, and have double checked the below steps:

- uTorrent has been allowed through the local firewall.
- I have forwarded the port to the correct local ip on my router.
- I have changed the port in the uTorrent webUI preferences, updated the forwarded port on my router and tried again (with a number of different ports).
- Uninstalled uTorrent, removed all relevant firewall exceptions and port forwarding rules, restarted the server, reinstalled uTorrent, and reinstated the firewall exception and port forwarding rules.

All to no avail.  As I mentioned, I use a number of other similar services, and am able to access them fine both internally and externally.

Comment: While uTorrent is running, check with http://canyouseeme.org/ against the port you are using to see if it visible.

Comment: Just checked it, and it can't see the port. It can see all my other forwarded ports just fine, and I can't see any difference in their configuration.

Comment: It has however now arbitrarily started to work again after the best part of a week despite me making no changes whatsoever. Very odd.